# Node fs.readFileSync returns a uInt8 array instead of raw buffer array?

Tags: arrays, node.js, binary, strong-typing

why is  this:

```
var myArrayBuffer = fs.readFileSync(file, null)
```

returning an uInt8 array instead of a just a arrayBuffer?  why does this seem to work?

```
var myArrayBuffer = fs.readFileSync(file, null).buffer;
var myAArray = new Uint16Array( myArrayBuffer.slice(266,(sizeofArray*sizeOfArrayElement));
```

Why would the fs.readFile parse my file into a uInt8 array?  Makes no sense, the file has a bunch of different datatypes that are not 1 byte long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because since v3.0.0 `Buffer` class inherits from `Uint8Array` class. Quoting [the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarray):

> `Buffer` instances are also `Uint8Array` instances. However, there are subtle incompatibilities with the `TypedArray` specification in ECMAScript 2015. For example, while `ArrayBuffer#slice()` creates a copy of the slice, the implementation of `Buffer#slice()` creates a view over the existing `Buffer` without copying, making `Buffer#slice()` far more efficient. [...]
>
> It is possible to
>   create a new `Buffer` that shares the same allocated memory as a
>   `TypedArray` instance by using the `TypeArray` object's `.buffer` property.

... which is exactly what's done in your example.

Comment: But why would someone ever need the uInt8Array?  You read a file directly into a buffer and deal with bytes?  If you read in a binary file the chance of it being all being uInt8 seems slim and just adds overhead, and in my case confusion and frustration.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. Yes, `Buffer` is also `Uint8Array` - but you don't have to use it as former.

Comment: I'm confused too;)  buffer doesnt seem to also be a uint8Array because the uint8Array.slice(266,length) gives me the Uint8array Indexes so its twice as much, where the buffer slice slices single bytes.  Just seems like added overhead

Comment: Yes, and that's also mentioned in the docs. Inheritance in this case means also overriding some methods' behaviour.